# Visibility of Custom PXProjection to Report Designer

Tags: reporting, acumatica, projection

Is there a trick or some sort of registration required to have a Custom PXProjection show up and be useable in the Report Designer (2022R1)

I have created some PXProjections for WIP reporting, similar the the Projections in PMReportProjections.cs, but they are not showing up in the Report designer.
I have published the dll/project and performed a LoadSchema - but nothing...

I have noticed that 'sometimes' even the standard PMWIP... projections don't show up in the Report Designer Schema either - although the report still runs OK...
I have also noticed that these PMWIP projections show up in 'live' Acumatica sites but not in locally installed test instances... perhaps a licensing issue??

Any clues appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I received some guidance from Acumatica Dev support which resolved the issue.

I had the projections nested in another class AKTWIPReportProjections - so I removed this class - and made the projections 1st level.

I also removed the [PXHidden] attribute as suggested. This attribute I think was the main issue.

So - for whatever reason - using the same code pattern as PMReportProjects.cs didn't work. But I can now use my custom projections in the report designer - so I am happy..